# Powershell - Excluding Word on a Text File and Print the Output

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to create a script to list all the users with local admin rights on a machine. The output will be saved to a txt file. Users that matches on the holder $User1, $User2, and $User3 will be excluded on the output.

Here's my code:

```
$User1 = "Administrator"
$User2 = "Admin1"
$User3 = "Admin2"

$LocalAdmin = Get-Content C:\AdminUsers.txt | Select-String -Pattern "$User1" -NotMatch | Select-String -Pattern "$User2" -NotMatch | Select-String -Pattern "$User3" -NotMatch

echo $LocalAdmin
```

The output shows like this:

```
Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
User1
User2
The command completed successfully.
```

How can I print only the user not the entire result like the below?

```
User1
User2
```

Thank you,

Comment: `echo $LocalAdmin.Members` ?

Comment: I tried to add the ".Members" but the output shows nothing (blank).

Comment: how are you generating the `C:\AdminUsers.txt` text file? what is the structure of that file? is it just a list of one-user-per-line? ///// to grab the user names of the members of a local admin group you can use >>> `(Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators).Name.ForEach({$_.Split('\')[-1]})` <<< ///// if you want to keep the domain/workgroup ... leave off the `.ForEach()`. ///// plus, that method will give you a nice, neat array to filter your exclusions out of. [*grin*]

Comment: this is the command I'm using to get the local group Administrator members:

     net localgroup Administrators >> C:\AdminUsers.txt

Comment: @Aouie - [1] to respond to a specific commenter ... use the `@UserName` method. that will send a notice to that person. [*grin*] ///// [2] why are you using that method? if you are using powershell ... you likely otta _use powershell_.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey so I tried the command that you've suggested and it works. However, it cut the username if there's domain user. Example: user1\Domain Admins. 

With your script, it will only shows like this: 
Domain Admins

Comment: @Aouie - so ... as i suggested, remove the foreach/split. that will give you the full value stored in the `.Name` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [Lee-Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70103717/powershell-excluding-word-on-a-text-file-and-print-the-output#comment123924433_70103717) that it would be easier to use `Get-LocalGroupMember`, but if you really want to use `net localgroup Administrators` and store the result in a text file, I would use:

```
$users = ((Get-Content -Path 'C:\Administrators.txt' -Raw).Trim() -split '(?m)^-+')[1] -split '\r?\n' | Select-Object -SkipLast 1
```

However, there should be no need to first write to a file if you do all from memory:

```
$users = ((net localgroup Administrators | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }) -join "`r`n" -split '(?m)^-+')[1] -split '\r?\n' | Select-Object -SkipLast 1
```

or

```
$users = (((net localgroup Administrators) -join "`r`n").Trim() -split '(?m)^-+')[1] -split '\r?\n' | Select-Object -SkipLast 1
```

Comment: Thanks Theo and @Lee-Dailey. I'll use this command instead as it is much cleaner. BTW, it's working fine on my end using this command.

Answer (score 0):

I found the right command now. Here it is:

```
net localgroup Administrators >> C:\AdminUsers.txt
$User1 = "Administrator"
$User2 = "Admin1"
$User3 = "Admin2"
$Text1 = "Members"
$Text2 = "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
$Text3 = "The command completed successfully."
(gc C:\AdminUsers.txt ) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content C:\AdminUsers1.txt 
$LocalAdmin = Get-Content C:\AdminUsers1.txt | Select-String -Pattern "$User1", "$User2", "$User3", "$Text1", "$Text2", "$Text3" -NotMatch 
echo $LocalAdmin
del C:\AdminUsers.txt
del C:\AdminUsers1.txt
```

Thanks for the help everyone.